# Dynamic Query with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

So I have an entity called `Customer`. A customer has a `name`, `address`,`gender`,`birthdate`,  `city` and `number of kids`.

I want to make it possible that the user can filter very dynamically on these fields. E.g. he can add a textfield to filter on name, then add another one to filter on another name, then two others textfields to filter between two dates for birthdate and so on... The user can also choose to either filter between to dates or equal one date. So it is not known beforehand how many filters the user wants to apply.

How would I build this kind of query, preferably with LINQ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Search for '.net query builder' and you should find tools that can do this for you.

Comment: Thanks @AlaaMasoud, I found a NuGet package DbExtensions and that, after some trial and error, did the trick!!

Answer (score 0):

Search for Dynamic Linq Query Builder for ASP.NET MVC 4. It is a nuget package that allows you to make dynamic linq queries.

Answer (score 0):

This would be similar to how you would write a SQL query, checking if a parameter is given and only then applying it as a filter.

```
    public class Customer
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Address;
        public string City;
        public string Gender;
        public DateTime Birthdate;
        public int NumberOfKids;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Customer> CustomerSearch(
        string partialName = null,
        string partialAddress = null,
        string partialCity = null,
        string gender = null,
        DateTime? exactBirthdate = null,
        DateTime? startDate = null,
        DateTime? endDate = null,
        int? minNumberOfKids = null)
    {
        // Sample data
        var customers = new [] {
            new Customer { Name = "Jack", Birthdate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-30), NumberOfKids = 1 },
            new Customer { Name = "Jill", Birthdate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-33).AddMonths(3), NumberOfKids = 2 },
            new Customer { Name = "Bob", Birthdate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-35), NumberOfKids = 3 }
        };
        var query =
            from c in customers
            where (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(partialName) || c.Name.Contains(partialName))
               && (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(partialAddress) || c.Address.Contains(partialAddress))
               && (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(partialCity) || c.City.Contains(partialCity))
               && (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(gender) || c.Gender == gender)
               && (!exactBirthdate.HasValue || c.Birthdate.Date == exactBirthdate.Value.Date)
               && (!startDate.HasValue || !endDate.HasValue || c.Birthdate.Date >= startDate.Value.Date && c.Birthdate.Date <= endDate.Value.Date)
               && (!minNumberOfKids.HasValue || c.NumberOfKids >= minNumberOfKids.Value)
            select c;
        return query;
    }
```

And call it something like this:

```
        test.CustomerSearch("J", minNumberOfKids: 2).ToList().ForEach(c => Console.WriteLine("J and 2 kids " + c.Name));
        test.CustomerSearch(exactBirthdate: DateTime.Today.AddYears(-35)).ToList().ForEach(c => Console.WriteLine("exact birthdate " + c.Name));
        test.CustomerSearch(startDate: DateTime.Today.AddYears(-36), endDate: DateTime.Today.AddYears(-31)).ToList().ForEach(c => Console.WriteLine("birthdate between " + c.Name));
```